# getElementsByTagName, Retrieving Specific nodeValue from nodeValue with more than one Value

Tags: php, arrays, dom

My XML file looks like this:

```
<Charge ID="01010101">

    <Type>SHIPPING</Type>

    <Description>Shipping</Description>

    <Amount>8.9500</Amount>

</Charge>

<Charge ID="10101010">

    <Type>TAX</Type>

    <Description>Sales Tax</Description>

    <Amount>0.0000</Amount>

</Charge>
```

I can make an array out of this

```
$getcharge = $doc->getElementsByTagName("Charge");

$array = array();
foreach ($getcharge as $node) {
$array[] = $node;
}
```

Using `print_r` I can see the `nodeValue` is constructed like this

```
[nodeValue] => 

    SHIPPING

    Shipping

    8.9500
```

Along the same lines, I can make an array from these nodeValues using

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("Charge") as $values) { {
    $result[] = $values->nodeValue;
}
}
```

Output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 

        SHIPPING

        Shipping

        8.9500


    [1] => 

        TAX

        Sales Tax

        0.0000


)
```

These child nodes are confusing me because they are not in individual nodeValue's, as seen in the array. They are in fact all one nodeValue.

All I am trying to do is loop over `Charge` and get the `<Type></Type>` and `<Amount></Amount>` into variables.

How do I get the single instance of `Type` and `Amount` amidst a nodeValue with multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get those batches of type, amount, description in each of those charges, you can already use `$values` as your context, you can also use the method `->getElementsByTagName` again. Example:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName("Charge") as $values) {
    // $values as each `Charge`
    $result[] = array(
        'id' => $values->getAttribute('ID'),
        'type' => $values->getElementsByTagName('Type')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'description' => $values->getElementsByTagName('Description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'amount' => $values->getElementsByTagName('Amount')->item(0)->nodeValue,
    );
}
```

Comment: `->getElementsByTagName` in the `ForEach` of the original as the key? Awesome, didn't think of that, makes sense.. works perfectly to output a nice array of each that is easy to parse through.